# Is my millijoule (mJ) calculation correct?

Tags: power, math

My partner and I are reviewing our products compliance with IEC 60601-1 and need verification of our millijoule calculations.

Our product outputs (up to) a 240v bi-phasic square wave, 240mA and maximum phase pulse width of 650uS. Each phase pulse is 120v. Our calculation is based on a 500ohm load (per the IEC standard).

With that data, here is what we calculated:

- 120v into 500 ohm = 28.8 watts
- 650uS = 0.00065 seconds
- 28.8 * 0.00065 = 0.01872 joules or 18.72 mJ

We're verifying this because we are so incredibly below the thresholds defined in the standard that we want to make sure there isn't something fundamentally wrong in our simple math.

Comment: 120 volts into 500 ohms is 240 mA. This does not agree with your spec. And a "maximum phase pulse width" suggests that the waveform is not a square wave, biphasic or otherwise. Otherwise, your calculations are correct.

Comment: I haven't reviewed your standard, but it's not clear to me if your "phase pulse" includes both phases, or not. If you need to include both phases and your timing only discusses one of those phases, then you should arrive at \$37.44\:\textrm{mJ}\$ for the maximum of the "biphasic" pulse. But I honestly can't tell what you meant.

Comment: Not your math, but your physics. You are calculating a physical quantity, not a unit. Also, millisiemens is not a unit of time.